# how to Change the global fog (image effect) color from a different script, possible in unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating three different environments. It contains three different color is deferent so how can I change Fog color run time?

Comment: I don't have the pro so I can't really tell the specific component. First Make a reference of the Class. GlobalFog myFog;

myFog = GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<GlobalFog>();

myFog.globalfogcolor <- I am not exactly sure if this is the correct name of the variable. Cause I don't have pro.

so continuing. myFog.globalFogColor = new Vector4(0,0,0,1);

Vector4 for the color type Red,Blue,Green, AlphaTransparency.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Look for fog related variables here:

> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings.html

Or a quick example:

> RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.blue;